# how to import the new installed module whie an old same module exists

Tags: python, pycurl, python-module, python-import

everybody!

the built-in pycurl module doesn't define Curl object

```
conn = pycurl.Curl()
```

> Error message:
>
> "pycurl" module has no attribute Curl

so I download the latest pycurl and install it,but it only works when I ran the code in interactive python interpreter,and I got the same error when I ran it as a script file.

It seems that when I run it as a script file,the old pycurl module will be included.

How can I import the new pycurl module or remove the old pycurl module?Thanks in advance.

PS.

in pydoc,the pycurl(old) module under '.' is clickable,redirecting to a page only saying "module has no attribute Curl",while the one(new) under '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' is gray and unclickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of when it is found. The basic import handler used in Python looks at the paths specified in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) in order to find a module, and after it has found something matching `pycurl` it will use it and not look further.

So, you need to either put your own copy of `pycurl` higher in the module search path, or in your own script do something like `sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/my-pycurl')` with the path to the directory containing the `pycurl` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works very well! it works when setting the first argument of sys.path.insert() to 0

Comment: @gbstack: if it doesn't work when you try to insert it in position 1, then it's finding the bad `pycurl` in the directory `sys.path[0]`, which is the script's directory. You're welcome to insert it at 0, but I find 1 is safer for such things as I know that modules/packages in my own directory will always prevail.